# openshift eclipse plugin installation

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jboss-tools

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: JBoss OpenShift Tools 2.6.0.Beta3-v20140718-1935-B44 (org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.feature.feature.group 2.6.0.Beta3-v20140718-1935-B44)
  Software currently installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.1.20140328-1905 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.1.20140328-1905)
  Software currently installed: Maven Integration for AJDT (Optional) 0.13.0.201107281640 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.ajdt.feature.feature.group 0.13.0.201107281640)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Object Teams Development Tooling Core 3.8.1.v_OTDT_r210_201206090452 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.1.v_OTDT_r210_201206090452)
    Object Teams Development Tooling Core 3.8.3.v_OTDT_r212_201301271217 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.3.v_OTDT_r212_201301271217)
    Java Development Tools Core 3.8.1.v20120531-0637 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.1.v20120531-0637)
    Object Teams Development Tooling Core 3.8.2.v_OTDT_r211_201209011847 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.2.v_OTDT_r211_201209011847)
    Java Development Tools Core 3.8.2.v20120814-155456 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.2.v20120814-155456)
    Java Development Tools Core 3.10.0.v20140604-1726 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.10.0.v20140604-1726)
    Java Development Tools Core 3.8.3.v20130121-145325 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.3.v20130121-145325)
    Java Development Tools Core 3.8.3.xx-201406301609-e42 (org.eclipse.jdt.core 3.8.3.xx-201406301609-e42)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Java Development Tools Launching Support 3.6.101.v20130111-183046 (org.eclipse.jdt.launching 3.6.101.v20130111-183046)
    Java Development Tools Launching Support 3.7.100.v20140428-1912 (org.eclipse.jdt.launching 3.7.100.v20140428-1912)
    Java Development Tools Launching Support 3.6.100.v20120523-1953 (org.eclipse.jdt.launching 3.6.100.v20120523-1953)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: AspectJ Development Tools Core 2.2.3.e42x-RELEASE-20130625-1400 (org.eclipse.ajdt.core 2.2.3.e42x-RELEASE-20130625-1400)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.6.0,3.9.0)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: AspectJ Development Tools 2.2.3.e42x-RELEASE-20130625-1400 (org.eclipse.ajdt.feature.group 2.2.3.e42x-RELEASE-20130625-1400)
    To: org.eclipse.ajdt.core 0.0.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.10.0.v20140606-1536 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.10.0.v20140606-1536)
    To: org.eclipse.jdt.core [3.10.0.v20140604-1726]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.8.0.v20120525-1249-8-8nFqlFNOfwKDRGz-pXJdG0GW83 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.8.0.v20120525-1249-8-8nFqlFNOfwKDRGz-pXJdG0GW83)
    To: org.eclipse.jdt.launching [3.6.100.v20120523-1953]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.8.0.v20120525-1249-8-8nFqlFNOfwKDRGz-pXLdGxEM83 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.8.0.v20120525-1249-8-8nFqlFNOfwKDRGz-pXLdGxEM83)
    To: org.eclipse.jdt.launching [3.6.100.v20120523-1953]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.8.1.v20120814-104540-8-8nFqpFNOfwKDRVz-tXLgJBep83 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.8.1.v20120814-104540-8-8nFqpFNOfwKDRVz-tXLgJBep83)
    To: org.eclipse.jdt.launching [3.6.100.v20120523-1953]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.8.1.v20120814-104540-8-8nFqpFNOfwKDRVz-tXOcL5d_83 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.8.1.v20120814-104540-8-8nFqpFNOfwKDRVz-tXOcL5d_83)
    To: org.eclipse.jdt.launching [3.6.100.v20120523-1953]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.8.2.v20130116-090414-8-8nFu3FNOfwKLRttdWQJ-2z-_83 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.8.2.v20130116-090414-8-8nFu3FNOfwKLRttdWQJ-2z-_83)
    To: org.eclipse.jdt.launching [3.6.101.v20130111-183046]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.8.2.v20130116-090414-8-8nFu3FNOfwKLRuqgXKIy9z0I83 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.8.2.v20130116-090414-8-8nFu3FNOfwKLRuqgXKIy9z0I83)
    To: org.eclipse.jdt.launching [3.6.101.v20130111-183046]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.1.20140328-1905 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.1.20140328-1905)
    To: org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.6.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: OpenShift Core 2.6.0.Beta3-v20140718-1935-B44 (org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.core 2.6.0.Beta3-v20140718-1935-B44)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.jdt.launching 3.7.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss OpenShift Tools 2.6.0.Beta3-v20140718-1935-B44 (org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.feature.feature.group 2.6.0.Beta3-v20140718-1935-B44)
    To: org.jboss.tools.openshift.express.core [2.6.0.Beta3-v20140718-1935-B44]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven Integration for AJDT (Optional) 0.13.0.201107281640 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.ajdt.feature.feature.group 0.13.0.201107281640)
    To: org.eclipse.ajdt.feature.group 1.5.0
```

Comment: Most likely the plugin requires a different version of Eclipse from the one you are using.

Comment: I am using Spring Tool Suite 3.6.0 who is based on Eclipse Luna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You installing latest development version of JBoss Openshif Tools form http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/development/luna/

I verified both 3.6.0 and 3.6.1 original clean installations and had no problems to install Openshift Tools.

Meantime I can see from error that your "m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.1.20140328-1905 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.1.20140328-1905)" doesn't match original version included in STS 3.6.0 which is "m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components)   1.5.0.20140606-0033 org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group".

I would suggest you to try to update to latest STS 3.6.1 and then install Openshift Tools again.

If you cannot update whole STS, I would try to update only m2e integration from luna repository before installing Openshif Tools.

I would also recommend to select "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" option during installation.

Comment: I update to the latest 3.6.1 but I still receive this log details:
  Software currently installed: Spring Tool Suite   Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Core Resource Management 3.8.0.v20120522-2034 (org.eclipse.core.resources 3.8.0.v20120522-2034)
    Core Resource Management 3.8.1.v20121114-124432 (org.eclipse.core.resources 3.8.1.v20121114-124432)
    Core Resource Management 3.9.0.v20140514-1307 (org.eclipse.core.resources 3.9.0.v20140514-1307)
    Core Resource Management 3.8.1.v20120802-154922 (org.eclipse.core.resources 3.8.1.v20120802-154922)

Comment: I reinstall a fresh new STS 3.6.1 and everything is ok

Comment: It could be upstream eclipse problem or p2 update issue, it is hard to detect and report. Good to know you could use reinstall option to make  it works.

Answer (score 3):

This basically says that plugins installed in your current Eclipse conflict with the plugins that JBoss OpenShift Tools (that you're apparently trying to install) is requiring:

> "Only one of the following can be installed at once:"

Latest Eclipse Luna (but also the prior Kepler relase) tries to resolve such issues and offers you different alternatives like replacing the existing, conflicting plugins and remove all the ones that require these.
Like greg-449 pointed out, my current guess is that you're using an old Eclipse version (Kepler or even older). JBoss OpenShift Tools 2.6.0.Beta3 requires Eclipse Luna.

Comment: I am using Spring Tool Suite 3.6.0 who is based on Eclipse Luna.